# Hyperledger Composer rest server version mismatch error

Tags: rest, docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm following [Using Google OAUTH2.0 with a REST server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) tutorial to implement a rest server in a docker container. But it's not working as expected. Whenever I try `docker logs rest` it shows an error:

> Error: Composer runtime (0.19.14) is not compatible with client (0.20.0)

But my composer version is 0.19.14. How to solve this issue?

Comment: What version of the composer rest server docker image are you using ? if it's `latest` that could actually be 0.20.0 try using an explicit version of the docker rest server ie
hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.14

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed that point. (Y)